# Use Python to Access Credential Store

Tags: python, python-3.x, credentials

I have used keyring to create some credentials in the windows credential store as well as created some using chrome or some other browser.

What I need is to find the names of the entries.  Can I some how leverage `keyring` to do this?  Or do I need to use something else?

Thank you

**UPDATE**

I am able to look through the credentials using the python library win32.

```
self._tn = []
self._creds = []
for i in win32cred.CredEnumerate():
    self._tn.append(i['TargetName'])
    self._creds.append(i)
```

The issue I run into an error when I try to obtain the username/password for this vault entry using keyring:

```
    return blob.decode('utf-16')
builtins.UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 6-7: illegal encoding
```

The code for getting the entry is as follows:

```
password = keyring.get_password(
        None, i['TargetName'])
```

Comment: Which ***names of the entries.*** are you referring to? the ones you've created previously?

Comment: I have one saved "Microsoft_Winlnet_<server>:443/<domain>

Comment: What I would like to do two things: list all entries in credential store and get a credential

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), e.g. the way you have written your question does not make clear where "blob" comes from, thus, it is difficult to help . Thanks.

Comment: @Isma The part about `blob` is the OP citing the stack-trace without explicitly telling us that's what they're doing. The line is from https://github.com/pradiptadas115/arm-template-workflow/blob/4e9e2a676c6226a7c2f16121f70583c0d8a0c82b/lib/keyring/backends/Windows.py#L71 in the `keyring` source.